# What's a good way to write a javascript regex for this?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have data that looks like this:

```
<n>Name</n><e>email</e><t>title</t>
```

Given a search term, I want to find all the lines in a file where the term is in the name or email. I have a regex that looks like this:

```
.*(?:<n>.*term.*</n>|<e>.*term.*</e>).*
```

(term is the search term). In other words, anything, followed by the <n> tag followed by stuff containing the term followed by </n> OR <e> followed by stuff containing the term followed by </e>. This works fine, only it performs horribly slowly. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search term in name or email you can use this regex:

```
<[ne]>.*?term.*?<\/[ne]>
```

Which should perform better than using OR clause in while regex.

Comment: I want to be able to get the entire line if it matches though. Does this do that?

Comment: This regex is for searching/testing each line. You should already have a line in your input string.

Comment: Also it is better if you show more code so that problem can be understood better.

Comment: what I mean is I have 1000 lines of the format specified. If the regex matches, I want the results to have all the lines that match.
`var search = new RegExp(search, "gi")`
`var results = data.match(search)`

Comment: ok then you can use this regex: `/^.*?<[ne]>.*?term.*?<\/[ne]>.*$/`

Comment: You might well be better off splitting it into lines first and then filtering the list with a regex like that.  (I haven't tried, but it's certainly worth investigating.)